# Link file to iCal event

Tags: osx-lion, calendar.app

In OS X Lion, is it possible to link a file to an iCal event? so that when I get the info of the event and click somewhere, the file gets opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a link, but you can add attachment to the event, and then when you click on the event so that you see the info, you can click on that filename and open the attachment.[image]

Comment: i can not see the field "attachments" in my ical version!? I am using os x lion

Comment: ok, it can only be done with calendars that are "on my mac" and not with calendars on iCloud, so it is not possible for me :(

Comment: I can put it under "url", and then in get "file: ...", but when I click it, it does not get opened